# How to query data from rds in airflow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, amazon-rds

I am a beginner in airflow, I am unable to find any docs for using

```
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.rds import RdsHook
```

I am using airflow 2.6.1, I want to query data.
I have created `rds_conn` in airflow connections, with additional keys like `host`, `port`, `db`, `username`, `password`.

I have tried creating an instance, but don't know how to query data. What is the procedure for this?

Comment: Share your code, it would be easier to understand and help you

Comment: The various operators in [airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.rds](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/rds.py#L373) might serve as a good example.

Comment: I didn't done anything, except
`rds_hook = RdsHook(aws_conn_id="rds_connection")`. I couldn't able to find any documentation related to querying data.